# Flutter Error running Gradle: ProcessException: Process "/home/benny/Documents/Afiaanyi/clone/mobile_app_codes/android/gradlew" exited abnormally

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter application am suppose to make little changes on, but the flutter is not running on my system, its showing many errors

- Error running Gradle:
  ProcessException: Process "/home/benny/Documents/Afiaanyi/clon/mobile_app_codes/android/gradlew" exited abnormally:
    Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Configure project :app
>   Observed package id 'system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86' in inconsistent location '/home/benny/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-27/google_apis/x86' (Expected '/home/benny/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-26/google_apis/x86')
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>
> Configure project :connectivity

Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':connectivity'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':connectivity:classpath'.
  >   Could not download kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.11)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.3.11/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.11.jar'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.3.11/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.11.jar'. Received status code 504 from server: Gateway Time-out
  >   Could not download kotlin-stdlib.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.11)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.11/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.11.jar'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.11/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.11.jar'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
  >   Could not download jsr305.jar (com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.jar'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.jar'.
  >   Remote host closed connection during handshake
  >   Could not download checker-qual.jar (org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.5.2)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/2.5.2/checker-qual-2.5.2.jar'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/2.5.2/checker-qual-2.5.2.jar'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8m 46s
  Command: /home/benny/Documents/Afiaanyi/clone/mobile_app_codes/android/gradlew app:properties

Pls how can i debug this one step by step to fix all errors 
Thanks for stopping to help

Answer (score 0):

Are you in Europe? We had the same for the most of the day since noon.

Here is their Incident Report for today's issue:
https://status.bintray.com/incidents/nmtzpzv59hsd